# Show only first row within a group for Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select always only the lowest number in ID2 and group by ID1

Table:

```
| ID1 | ID2 |  Name  | Phone |
|  1  |  1  | Max    |  123  |
|  1  |  2  | Ben    |  254  |
|  1  |  3  | Robert |  541  |
|  2  |  1  | Andy   |  515  |
|  2  |  2  | Carl   |  631  |
```

This is the output that I want:

```
| ID1 |  Name   | Phone |
|  1  |  Max    |  123  |
|  2  |  Andy   |  515  |
```

Can anyone help me with the correct query for microsoft sql server please...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CTE and a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID1, ID2,  Name, Phone,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID1 ORDER BY ID2 ASC)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT ID1, ID2,  Name, Phone 
FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```